# Why am I seeing unreadable tokens in Apache error log

Tags: php, apache, logging, centos, hex

I'm running a production server LAMP stack Centos 6.6(Final), PHP version 7.1.27 with Apache 2.4.38. Seeing errors in the Apache log where the function names, and stack trace have been obfuscated, with what appears to be hex code.

`[Wed Mar 20 10:57:13.679432 2019] [php7:error] [pid 64941:tid 140335621515008] [client <HIDDEN>] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function $\xf0H\x89\xfbH\x89l$\xe8L\x89l$\xf8H\x83\xec(H\x8b/Lcm\bN\x8d,/\x8b}\x0cLc\xe7N\x8d$#A\x0f\xb6D$\b<\x06u9I\x8b\x04$\x8bU\x14\xf6@\x05\x02u\x03\x83() in :342\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in Unknown on line 342, referer: https://<HIDDEN>`

Comment: Could it be a malicious script being injected somewhere? https://security.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ might be worth a shot (read their tour / ask guide).

Comment: It looks like obfuscated malicious script. Type client's ip address in google and see if it is included in any blacklists.

Comment: @Script47 The I.P address is verified as being one of our internal users. They are authorised to use the application and from what we can see this was an isolated error.

Comment: It looks like these tokens are memory references. Not sure why they haven't been converted to human readable form for the log.